# Change folder permission after deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have in my application a folder where I save files uploaded by users. This folder needs write permision for the apppool user. Untill now I did it manualy.

My question is, if this could be done somehow automatic ? Maybe running some script after deploy or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this out myself, but it seems as if you could do this with the deployment package stuff in vs2010:

http://leethams.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/modifying-directory-permissions-with-web-deployment/